# Я хочу установить базу данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows

Я все перепробовал, но так и не смог установить, интернет работает нормально, но пишет ошибка подключения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите `Log`.

Comment: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled). Ended configuration step: Starting the server